# I am getting an error: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) and im not sure how to fix it

Tags: python, discord.py

im making a music bot using discord.py and im g

```
class music_cog(commands.cog):
  def __init__(self,client):
    self.client = client

    self.is_playing == False
    self.is_paused == False

    self.music_queue = []
    self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
    self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    self.vc = None
```

the erroris : class music_cogs(commands.cog):
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

im not sure about how to fix this and whats wrong here

Comment: Based on the documentation, I think your base class is supposed to be `commands.Cog` with an uppercase `C`.

Comment: You must provide enough code to reproduce the given error.